# Función e javascript que me arroja lineas vacias

Tags: javascript

Buenas noches, he estado practicando mi código pero me he encontrado con un problema y no logro detectar el error, ya que al invocar varias funciones me devuelven unos caracteres en una lista ordenada, pero algunas lineas están vacías y no entiendo el por qué.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prueba JavaScript</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = iniciar;

    function iniciar() {
        generarListas("Lista1","uno","dos","tres","cuatro","cinco","seis");
    }

    function generarListas() {
        var s = '<ol>';
        var i;

        for(i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
            s = s+"<li>"+arguments[i]+"<li>";
        }

        s = s+"</lo>";

        var elemento1 = document.getElementById(arguments[0]);
        elemento1.innerHTML = s;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Lista1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al momento de concatenar las etiquetas `li` no realizas el cierra de esta `</li>` al final de la línea dentro del `for`. modificar esto y funcionará perfectamente.

```
s = s+"<li>"+arguments[i]+"</li>";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me percaté de eso.

Comment: Y el cierre <\lo> está mal

Answer (score 1):

## Problemas de seguridad

Hay que tratar de no usar una variable de texto para armar código HTML si el contenido proviene de texto que viene del usuario. **Cada vez que uses `innerHTML` hay riesgo**

### Solución Alternativa (sin user innerHTML).

```
function generarListas() {
    var ol = document.createElement('ol');
    var i;

    for(i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = arguments[i];
        ol.appendChild(li);
    }

    var elemento1 = document.getElementById(arguments[0]);
    elemento1.appendChild(ol);
}
```

#### Explicación de la solución

- document.createElement es la función para crear los elementos, en este caso 'OL' y 'LI'
- appendChild es la función para meter elementos dentro de otros
- textContent es la propiedad para meter texto dentro de un elemento. Esta propiedad hace las traducciones necesarias para que todos los signos (tal como `&`, `<` y `>`) y los acentos se vean bien.

#### Problemas posibles de pegar HTML

1. Que los textos contengan caracteres prohibidos dentro del HTML tal como `&`, `<` y `>` cada navegador podría mostrarlos en distinta forma
2. Que un usuario malicioso pusiera un texto html con algún link que incluya un `<script>` o algo parecido

Eso puede ocurrir tanto si el texto es introducido en el momento por el usuario como si lo ingresó previamente en un formulario que luego fue a una base de datos.

Aún cuando "por ahora" la función no se use con datos del usuario, el día de mañana podrías querer usarla. Lo mejor es programar sin pegar HTML desde el momento 0